# Code Behind in SharePoint

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

I have a .aspx page and a .aspx.cs page. These were created in VS. I've copied the solution folder to SharePoint using SPD. When browsing the page I get an error

Parser Error Message: The codefile attribute on the page directive is not allowed in this page. I've looked around on the web and found 3 possible ways. The first seems over-complex. Are options 2 or 3 possible. Have tried oprion 2 but doesnt appear to work.

1. Ive seeen Andrew Connells blog: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/UsingCodeBehindFilesInSharePointSites.aspx
2. I've seen another article referring to changing the web.config file to run the code behind:
3. Is it possible to use inheritance instead?
   http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentlegacy/thread/87604ae8-72eb-404f-9ea1-2692038f36f5

Hope someone can help on this.

Comment: The problem is, that the assemblies (dll's) are not in the bin folder. So it's not compiled, see davids answer) But why didn't you create a webpart? It supports coded visual webparts (on farm solutions).

Comment: what you actually trying to do ?

Comment: We need to display sql results of another system on a SP page. The page has a gridview. Code exists in VS and contains files (default.aspx, Default.aspx.cs , data.cs and .sql) code-behind and a class. Main purpose is to show status of external system. I added the entire folder into a new web using  SPD (All Files) http://sp20104/alerts/EmailAlerts
Possible to browse location and this is where error reported. I’ve tried looking for the physical files but cannot find them. Have they been serialised to database?
cont..

Comment: Despite not finding files is it best to create a webpart , wsp or application page. If yes how can I do this with the existing VS project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're copying the ASPX and the ASPX.CS file into SharePoint, which I don't believe is supported. You need to compile the project, and deploy it ideally via a WSP solution, but you could copy the DLL and the ASPX (not the .cs) manually.

I'd bet that your issue is a limitation around security, which would deny people easy code access to a farm.

As far as the masterpage is concerned, you can get away without using one, and just use your own ASPX page standalone.

HTH

Comment: Hi From the anwers above are there multiple ways in achieving my requirements? i.e. Application page, Web Part?
You mention the limitation in security, can I override this? 
Someone else produced this and gave me the project files. In VS shall I build and copy DLL to SharePoint ?

Comment: It all depends on your requirements. To @Sascha's point, you could build the project in VS, then copy the DLL to the web application's BIN directory. That should allow your ASPX pages to run. The code will run within the SP application pool, but permissions are restricted via the web.config file.

Comment: In the end, you will have to compile the project, you can't run uncompiled code in SharePoint.

Comment: Additionally, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798412.aspx for more around SP's execution models.

Comment: Is this similiar to option 1 that I've mentioned in my question?

Comment: Option 1 is pertaining to SharePoint v3, or 2007. What version are you running on? Development in SP2010 supports code behind files in VS, but it has to be compiled. The link I shared explains the different execution models, once you compile your code, you need to put it somewhere, this article explains your options.

Comment: I'm running SP2010. If I copy the dll manually (without wsp) how does my page reference it?

Comment: This is where VS helps. The final compiled solution modifies your ASPX pages, removes the codefile attribute and ensures a reference to your assembly exists. A compiled ASPX page should look something like `<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>` `<@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.ActionRedirectPage"` using your assembly and class names

Comment: **DISCLAIMER:** I feel compelled to say that this is a hackish method of deploying to SharePoint. Microsoft has provided the necessary tools and methods for deploying custom code into SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks for the help.. If this is a hackish method, which micosoft tools and methods are recomended? Would it be wsp's?

Comment: Yes, VS has SharePoint tools for creating, compiling, and packaging everything into a WSP file for deployment. There's a slew out there on development, some hands on labs: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=17215

Comment: Hi I've created a Webpart and works!, Thanks

Previously, it was mentioned that sharepoint will run complied code only. Is this the case with anything created in SDP also? I think I've created an aspx page in with srver code and it runs.. so whats the situation here?

Comment: SPD shouldn't allow you to run server side code, at least it never let me before ;) I'm happy to hear your web part works, congrats! If this answer is satisfactory please consider marking your question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

you can create an [applicationpage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231581.aspx)

An application page is an ASP.NET Web page that is designed for use in a SharePoint Web site. Application pages are a specialized type of ASP.NET page. The primary difference between an application page and a standard ASP.NET page is that an application page contains content that is merged with a SharePoint master page. A master page enables application pages to share the same appearance and behavior as other pages on a site.

Visual Studio enables you to design application pages by using a designer. The designer displays a content area for each content placeholder that is defined in a master page. You can design the application page by dragging controls to these content areas.